# return function call by reference

Tags: c++

[image]

I am reading the textbook, then I encounter the function as above "Sales_data::combine()".

If I do

```
Total.combine(trans);
```

in which Total and trans are Sales_data, after this function call, would the object Total be changed? And what's the point of returning the *this?

Comment: Please replace the image with text from the book. Images are not search friendly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> after this function call, would the object `Total` be changed?

It will be changed if `trans.units_sold` and/or `trans.revenue` is not zero, as the same fields in `Total` are affected by the `+=` statements in the function implementation.

> And what's the point of returning the *this?

It lets you chain further calls to member functions, so you could do something like:

```
Total.combine(trans1).combine(trans2);
```

That would combine values from both `trans1` and `trans2` into `Total`.

If `Sales_data` has other functions, you could use the return value of `combine` to access them too.  For example, if there's an `operator<<(std::ostream&, const Sales_data&)` function for streaming a `Sales_data` object, you could write...

```
std::cout << Total.combine(trans1) << '\n';
```

...which would merge the values from `trans1` into `Total` before printing the updated values from `Total`.